# cross compiling for android using NDK fails with compiler error

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I'm compiling a nexus one android kernel from source as found on [HTCs developer website](http://developer.htc.com/images/icon_download.gif).  I've obtained an ARM tool chain by DLing the [android NDK](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r5c-linux-x86.tar.bz2) from the android dev site.  I am able to run make clean and make defconfig without incident, but when I run make, it only gets so fare before running into compiler errors.

Currently i see the following:

> $MY_DIR/nexus_one/arch/arm/include/asm/glue.h:156:29: error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter

The offending line is:

```
1  /*
2  * Instruction Fault Status Register.  (New register as of ARMv6)
3  * If processor has IFSR then set value, else set translation fault
4  */
5 #if defined(CONFIG_CPU_ABRT_EV7) || defined(CONFIG_CPU_ABRT_EV6)
6 # define CPU_PABORT_IFSR(reg)    mrc p15, 0, reg, cr5, cr0, 1         @asm macro;
7 #else
8 # define CPU_PABORT_IFSR(reg)    mov reg, #5                          @asm macro;
9 #endif
```

Specifically, line 8 above is what hoses the compiler.  Apparently you can't have that second # sign, but i'm not really sure whats going on in this code, and it looks pretty important so i don't want to touch it.

I'm guessing i'm compiling with the wrong tool chain maybe?  Or perhaps i have configured things wrong somehow?  Does any one have any idea what this is all about?

thanks,
brian

Comment: fyi, i've tried this now with like 4 different tool chains, so i'm starting to think that the specific cross-compiler is not the issue.  i'm not sure what else to look at though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was nothing to do with the specific toolchain.  The # sign needed 'escaping' of some sort.  The solution was as follows:

```
/* this is needed to get the mov reg, 5 macro to compile and function correctly */
#define hash_hackery #
#define f(x) x

#if defined(CONFIG_CPU_ABRT_EV7) || defined(CONFIG_CPU_ABRT_EV6)
# define CPU_PABORT_IFSR(reg)   mrc p15, 0, reg, cr5, cr0, 1         @asm macro;
#else
# define CPU_PABORT_IFSR(reg)   mov reg, f(hash_hackery)5            @asm macro;
#endif
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386597/how-to-print-a-pound-hash-via-c-preprocessor) was very informative in finding the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to use CodeSourcery toolchain for Linux for compiling Linux kernel.

- [CodeSourcery GNU Toolchain for ARM Processors: 2008q1-126 version](http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/release324)

Comment: that was the first one i triedi *think*.  i'll try again and see if it makes a difference.  thanks!

Comment: just curious; what in particular makes you recommend this toolchain?

Comment: so i had previously tried a similar but distinct toolchain from codesourcery and have seen the same error now in both cases (plus with the ndk toolchain).  so i guess the issue must be something else.