# C Macro utilizing immediate values in embedded arm asm - armcc

Tags: c, macros, escaping, armcc

The closest threads to my question are these [Escaping a # symbol in a #define macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135822/escaping-a-symbol-in-a-define-macro) and [How to print a pound / hash via C preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386597/how-to-print-a-pound-hash-via-c-preprocessor), but they don't exactly answer my question. More explicitly, the second doesn't seem to work with the armcc compiler; it just prints hash4 and not the symbol defined by hash.  Chris Lutz was especially disparaging of trying use a macro for this functionality in the second post, so maybe this is the incorrect method all together. I would like more thoughts than just one persons, though.

The problem is the following: I'm trying to write a macro that defines an embedded asm C function utilizing a macro. I've essentially implemented it except for one issue... expressing an immediate value.  Immediate values' syntax requires (I believe) a pound symbol which is also the "stringify" symbol for the preprocessor.  So, is it possible to escape a # symbol in a C macro?

The primary purpose behind this is to wrap an isr with a pico kernels thread context management procedures and that new procedure's function pointer will eventually be passed to the vectored interrupt controller.

Here's the code:

```
#define ISR_THREAD_MGMT(ISR_FUNC,FUNC_NAME) \
__asm void FUNC_NAME ( void ); \
__asm void FUNC_NAME (void ) \
{ \
    STMDB sp!, {r0-r3}; \
    MRS   r0, SPSR; \
    SUB   lr, lr, #4; \        <----- Heres the problem
    STMDB sp!, {r0, r10, r12, lr}; \
    bl _thread_vectored_context_save; \
    bl ISR_FUNC; \
    b _thread_context_restore; \
}
```

I hope I've explained everything in sufficient detail. If not, please don't hesitate to ask for any more details.

Comment: My first instinct was "don't use a macro for this", but clearly you've already seen someone else say that, so I'm not sure what you expect us to say - you are trying to use a macro pre-processor to do things it was never designed to do. If you were using at&t syntax, if would magically work because $ [indication of constant] is not a preprocessor "special character". One solution would of course be to actually write out FUNC_NAME and ISR_FUNC in individual functions - or not use the C compiler for assembler code...

Comment: Overall, I was wanting a larger consensus than one person's thoughts. So, you are saying specifying embedded assembly instructions as a macro is outside its intended use? Weren't macros originally written to inline function calls?  Furthermore, a text preprocessor that doesn't let you write all symbols?  Seems strange to me...

Comment: The C preprocessor is intended for C - it's part of its name. When C was designed, inline assembler was not part of the scope - the compiler would produce assembler, and then assemble through the system assembler - if you wanted to add assembler code yourself, you wrote a `something.s` file - which is still a valid option. Most assemblers do have a macro functionality to let you produce the same code over and over with variations.

Comment: Yes, I have it implemented through that method, I just felt since arm has an embedded assembler it wasn't as concise to have extra asm files lying around. I just find it strange that a text preprocessor doesn't allow you to print any characater. Why the restriction do you think? Ease of coding on the parser side? Or they just never saw the use case?

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is, why restrict potential functionality?

Comment: Well, your use-case isn't exactly "mainstream", is it? But by all means contact ARM and say "Can you please make sure I can use your preprocessor to make inline assembler with # work" - they may add an extension of some sort. I don't see having a "interrupts.s" or something similar in an operating system as "extra asm files" - it's what I expect. Linux has it, Symbian OS has it, as far as I understand, Windows does the same, as does OSE - along with a proprietary OS for Xerox that I don't remember the name of [but I ported the code for].

Comment: Well, I respectfully disagree. Seems to me a text pre processor should allow you to display whatever text you desire.  Let the compilers/assemblers decide what works.  If I want to display a comment with a pound in without quotation marks, I see no reason that it should be disallowed at that level.  Thanks for the discourse.

Comment: Also, my request would be "allow me to specify whatever character I want at the preprocessor stage", not so specific as "make inline assemblers work."  Once again, the resolution of whether there is a problem should be handled at a later stage in my mind.

Comment: Yes, but the C preoprocessor will need SOME characters that it uses for it's own purposes. You can use ALMOST any nonsense you like in a preprocessor - as long as it's within valid C character set in general [that is, you MAY not be able to use simplified chineese or russian in the preprocessor]. There is, as far as I understand, only a few exceptions to that - # being the one that comes to mind immediately.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but isn't that usually the point of having some sort of escape sequence? So you can have your cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second of your referenced questions shows you how to do it:

```
#define hash #
#define mash(x) x
#define immediate(a) mash(hash)a
#define ISR_THREAD_MGMT(ISR_FUNC,FUNC_NAME) \
__asm void FUNC_NAME ( void ); \
__asm void FUNC_NAME ( void ) \
{ \
    STMDB sp!, {r0-r3}; \
    MRS   r0, SPSR; \
    SUB   lr, lr, immediate(4); \
    STMDB sp!, {r0, r10, r12, lr}; \
    bl _thread_vectored_context_save; \
    bl ISR_FUNC; \
    b _thread_context_restore; \
}

ISR_THREAD_MGMT(abc,def)
```

Output:

```
# 1 "x.c"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "x.c"
# 17 "x.c"
__asm void def ( void ); __asm void def ( void ) { STMDB sp!, {r0-r3}; MRS r0, SPSR; SUB lr, lr, #4; STMDB sp!, {r0, r10, r12, lr}; bl _thread_vectored_context_save; bl abc; b _thread_context_restore; }
```

Output reformatted:

```
# 1 "x.c"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "x.c"
# 17 "x.c"
__asm void def ( void );
__asm void def ( void )
{
    STMDB sp!, {r0-r3};
    MRS r0, SPSR;
    SUB lr, lr, #4;
    STMDB sp!, {r0, r10, r12, lr};
    bl _thread_vectored_context_save;
    bl abc;
    b _thread_context_restore;
}
```

I'm not convinced it is a good idea, but it does at least work.

Comment: I tried that using the armcc compiler to no avail.  Are you using gcc?  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Do you really need `immediate(4)`? Perhaps `mash(hash)4` would work just as well? A quick test, using `gcc -E ...`, seems to show this.

Comment: armcc doesn't seem to resolve the hash define properly within function-like macros, unfortunately.  It simply prints the parameter 'hash'

Comment: I don't know what `armcc` is up to...but I don't think it is following the C standard.  @JosephQuinsey: The notation `immediate(4)` looks to me more recognizable than `mash(hash)4`, so I'd rather use it — if only the relevant C preprocessor worked with it.

Comment: I think I'm going to contact an ARM representative tomorrow, if I don't have a solution by then.  They'll most likely say it is nonexistent functionality, but I'll keep you informed regardless of the response.  Thanks for the effort, guys.

Comment: Crap, the method described here works... I had hash undef'd below it. Sign, this is a non issue.  Sorry, guys.